# Where is the default .p4config file located?

Tags: perforce

I changed the P4PORT variable with the following command:

```
p4 configure set P4PORT=<local IPv4>:80
```

But now I am unable to connect to, or even start the perforce server. I was hoping that maybe someone would know where the default location for the .p4config file (I don't even think I know its proper name...) is so I can manually change the P4PORT value back to something that works.

Answer (score 2):

`p4 configure` (server configurables persisted in the server db) is completely separate from `P4CONFIG` (client configurables persisted in a client-side text file).

If you've set `P4PORT` to an invalid value via `p4 configure`, you'll want to:

1. Check the log file (look for a file with `log` in its name in the `P4ROOT` directory) to confirm the error.  I'm guessing you'll see an error about being unable to listen on that port.
2. Fix `P4PORT` via `p4d -cset`.  (You don't want to mess around with `db.config` manually.)
3. Try again to restart the server, and start from step 1 if needed.

See `p4d -h`:

```
   Configuration options:
        -cshow
        '-cset [server#]variable=value'
        '-cunset [server#]variable'

        This syntax provides a limited subset of the functionality of the
        'p4 configure' command, and is useful for accessing the configuration
        when the server is down. The '-cshow' flag displays the contents of
        the db.config table, similar to 'p4 configure show allservers'.
        The '-cset' and '-cunset' flags set or unset a configurable. When
        using set or unset, enclose the entire expression in quotation marks,
        and on Windows, use double quotation marks, not single ones.
```

Comment: Thank you samwise! I ended up resolving this by moving to the servers root directory, and executing the following command
`p4d -r . "-cset ServerID#P4PORT=<new hostname>:80"`

Comment: Great!  FWIW, unless you're doing it just to dodge a firewall rule, I'd recommend against using port 80 since that's usually used for web servers and p4d isn't one.  :)  The standard Perforce port is 1666.